# Determine which User created an Azure (Ubuntu) Linux Server (with "Quick Create")

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, ubuntu-12.04

I've created an Ubuntu Linux Server on my Azure Virtual Machines.

I used the "Quick Create" instead of gallery and entered a password, but didn't choose a user name (wasn't an option).  Now I'm tring to SSH to my Server using password and "root" and it says- access denied.

Which user was created by the "Quick Create" wizard??

Thanks,
Aviad

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should try with `azureuser` as far as I can see it's the default username that is created using the 'quick create', and 'gallery' options.

This is the dialog I remember getting:

[image]